# Pandas: Returns a view versus a copy, tuple construction

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Env:  Python 3.6, Pandas

I have a line of code that reads:

```
df['column_1'][df['column_2'].str.contains('keyword')] = df['column_3']
```

The code is designed to look at `column_2` and if the `keyword` is present to set `column_1` string to what is in `column_3`.  It works just fine and does what I would expect.  But it throws [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) warning:   `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`.

Based on the docs and the examples I changed to:

```
df.loc[:,('column_1', df['column_2'].str.contains('keyword'))] = df['column_3']
```

But, this code throws:  `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`.

I believe the error is a result of the second element of the tuple.  There is another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48323370/pandas-indexing-view-versus-copy) that works with the same construction (and I can run that without the err).  There are a several other similar questions but none of them deal with a search on a column in the tuple.  So that narrows it down to how do I write `df['column_2'].str.contains('keyword')` in a way that will work in a tuple?

Or is there something else that I'm missing?

**UPDATE:**

After more research, it maybe relevant that I setup `column_1` by

```
df['column_1'] = np.nan    #numpy NaN
```

It seems that how the column is constructed can also cause this type of error.  The dtype as a NaN is `float64`. I've tried recasting `.astype(str)` without any change.

Comment: Is the df is subset from another df ?

Comment: no - everything is happening in a single df.  It is used to .read_csv() make some changes and then .to_csv() [new file].